# Assigning a variable outside of a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm to trying to assign a value to a variable that was getting by input in HTML. But it gives me the actual input if I assign the variable inside of the function only. I was trying to build a simple calculator. I will be thankful to you if you can help me. Refer to the following code.

```js
let num1 = document.getElementById("input");
let num2 = document.getElementById("input2");

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
}
```

```html
<input Id="input">
<input Id="input2">
<button onClick="myFunction()">
    <span id="p"></span>
```

Comment: what do you expect? you have two DOM-Elements in num1 and num2, do you want to append them inside the paragraph ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I get *a* problem (which is that the output isn't useful) but that's not the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   const num1 = document.getElementById("input").value;
   const num2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
   document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: parse the value not element

Answer (score 1):

```js
let num1 = document.getElementById("input");
let num2 = document.getElementById("input2");

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = parseInt(num1.value) + parseInt(num2.value);
}
```

```html
<input Id="input">
<input Id="input2">
<button onClick="myFunction()">Add Numbers</button>
    <span id="p"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <hmtl>
 <head><title>Document</title></head>
 <body>
 <input Id = "input">
 <input Id = "input2" >
 <button onClick= 'myFunction(document.getElementById("input").value,document.getElementById("input2").value)'>
 <span id="p"></span>

 <script>
 function myFunction(n1, n2){
 document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = parseInt(n1)+parseInt(n2);
 }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, so that everyone can understand it better.

Comment: @Shakya you can also additionally use input type="number" to try forcing only number input